# Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco' or one of its dependencies. - error after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, sap-dotnet-connector

We have implemented SAP connectivity project using .NET Web Application. We used 2 dlls `SAPnco.dll`, `sapnco_utils.dll`.

When we try to run this application in visual studio 2019 it is working fine, But after publishing the project IIS (localhost), it is throwing below Error.

We tried by enabling to 32bit, 64 bit in Visual Studio, but we are getting same error. We also enabled 32 bit in DefaultApplicationPool, but issue still exists. Can anyone please help me out to resolve.

[image: IIS Error]

Comment: Please make sure that `IIS_IUSRS` has full access to `SAPnco.dll, sapnco_utils.dll` these two dlls. you can also try to change the identity of the AppPool that your app is using to NetworkService.

Comment: @samwu  Thanks for your suggestions. I tried the suggested ways, but still getting the same exception.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: incorrect format is most likely the wrong "bitness" assembly. You could force either 32 or 64 bit in the visual studion project settings and make sure you supply the matching sapnco libraries.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek is correct.  Set all "bitness" to x64.  On "Web" tab of project and in the "Run" toolbar.